# Angular how to add a form group to a TR component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table that is looping over an array of form control values.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let t of intakeForm.get('tasks').value let i = index; trackBy:trackByIndex" [taskTR]="t" [ui]="uiOptions" [intakeForm]="intakeForm"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Within my `TR` component, the HTML is all of the `TD` data, pretty standard stuff.

However, I have an input within one of those TD's that I need to assign a `formControlName` to.

When I try and do this, it tells me that it needs to be within a `formGroup` which I totally understand.

However, if I try and wrap all the TD's with a formGroup div, it makes the table HTML invalid.

**TR Component HTML:**

```
<td>{{ row.User.FirstName }} {{ row.User.LastName }}</td>
<td>{{ row.Tool.ToolName }}</td>
<td class="col-md-9">
    <ng-select  [items]="ui.adminRoles.options" 
                bindLabel="RoleName" 
                bindValue="Role"
                placeholder="Select one or more roles" 
                [multiple]="true"
                [clearable]="false" 
                (add)="addRole($event, row)" 
                formControlName="someField"
                (remove)="removeRole($event, row)">
    </ng-select>
</td>
```

The above results in the error:

```
ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
```

How could I add a form group to this while still keeping the HTML valid? ie, a div inside a table row is not valid syntax.

Comment: You can add the FormGroup directive on any HTML element, so you can just add it on the <tr> tag no ?

Comment: @PierreMallet I thought so but it appears like its gotta wrap the form controls and adding it to the TR doesnt seem to do that. I am just unable to put it in the TR component directly

Comment: Could you post an example on stackblitz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using `FormGroup`-Elements in your template, you should set `FormGroup`-Directive. The easiest way to do this is to wrap your table with `form`-Tag and add `FromGroup`-Directive to this `form`-Tag. Like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="yourFormGroup">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let t of intakeForm.get('tasks').value let i = index; trackBy:trackByIndex" [taskTR]="t" [ui]="uiOptions" [intakeForm]="intakeForm">    </tr>
  </tbody>
</form>
```